# Is there a workaround as to how to return inside a conditional statement in a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, return

I am trying to solve a problem that I've already done with jQuery but trying to teach myself React at the same time and redoing the solution doesn't seem to be as smooth as I thought - what a surprise. Anyways just for now I'm trying to output a list of the items and prices onto my React app but I cannot get it to return JSX inside of the if statement.

I understand JSX has issues at run time with if statements but I have tried ternary operators as well and I cannot find a work around. When I try the ternary operation I get an error on my return statement saying *'expression expected'*.

```
        this.state.itemsWithPrice.map(x =>
            data.map(n => {
                if(n==x.market_hash_name){
                    // alert(x.market_hash_name+x.price);
                    return (
                        <li>{x.price}</li>
                    )
                }
        }))

       return <h1>works here</h1>
```

So pretty much the data array has the names of the items I am interested in and itemsWithPrice has the names + additional information so I am trying to only return the items of interest which is why I need to return inside the if (x.price and more after I figure out how). Is there a work around for this?

Comment: You are iterating over `itemsWithPrice` but then iterate over another variable `data` which seems to be unrelated to `itemsWithPrice`. This seems odd. What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Why not use `filter()` to only get the items you're interested in? Then you can chain `map()`. Right now, you are nesting calls to `map()` and since `map()` returns an array, you get an array (with JSX) inside an array. This may be the reason it's not rendering.

Comment: @chris `data` contains a subset of the `market_hash_name`s that i want to pull from the larger data set that contains more info on those items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter` does that.

```
data
    .filter(n => fulfillsSomeCondition(n)) // other n are just removed from further consideration
    .map(n => <li>some content</li>)
```

Comment: oh god that's a duh moment on my end. I was trying reduce instead of filter at one point.... thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the data before returning:

```
const filteredData = this.state.itemsWithPrice.map(x => data.includes(x.market_hash_name));

filteredData.map(n => <li>{x.price}</li>);
```